# Google Now voice in Java

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech, google-now

Seeing as Android is open-source, would it be possible to extract the speech libraries of the OS? The voice of Google now is the most natural sounding one I have ever heard, and could almost be mistaken for that of a human. It would be perfect for my home automation system.

I know jellybean is not released yet, so there is probably no access to the source at this time. There is also the possibility that the voice is not client-based (I know Google Now is not).

Comment: Open source does not automatically mean "without copyright". Check the specific licence

Comment: @SJuan76 But for private use it is virtually always allowed